# Flex box shrink is not working where wrap a child, I just want box2 be 200px instead of 300px

Tags: css, flexbox

When i use flex box and flex shrink, I wrap a child into a div, It does not work as i want.

### I want box 2 be 200px instead of 300px.
And why shrink is not working inside.

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <style>
    #content {
      display: flex;
      width: 300px;
      background: blue;
    }
    
    #content div {}
    
    .box {
      flex-shrink: 0;
      width: 100px;
    }
    
    .box1 {
      flex-shrink: 1;
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .box2 {
      flex-shrink: 1;
      width: 300px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="content">
    <div class="box" style="background-color:red;">A</div>
    <div class="box1" style="background-color:blue;">
      <div class="box2" style="background-color:green;">B</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

How can anyone help me?

Comment: min-width:0 to box1

Comment: It works! Thx my bro! But why , could you tell me the reason.

Comment: see the duplicate question